# Calculating L2 norm using Keras Lambda layer doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I have the following custom layer:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda
def l2_norm(x):
    x = x ** 2
    x = K.sum(x, axis=1)
    x = K.sqrt(x)
    return x
```

which I later use in my model in this way:

```
class Arq(object):
def __init__(self, nb_filters_1=10, nb_filters_2=20, lenght_filters=4,
             pool_size_1=4, pool_size_2=2, dropout_prob_1=0.5,
             dropout_prob_2=0.5, frames=2580, frequency=128,
             dense_size=100, nb_classes=8):
    self.nb_filters_1 = nb_filters_1
    self.nb_filters_2 = nb_filters_2
    self.lenght_filters = lenght_filters
    self.pool_size_1 = pool_size_1
    self.pool_size_2 = pool_size_2
    self.dropout_prob_1 = dropout_prob_1
    self.dropout_prob_2 = dropout_prob_2
    self.frames = frames
    self.frequency = frequency
    self.dense_size = dense_size
    self.nb_classes = nb_classes

def build_convolutional_model(self):
    input_placeholder = Input(shape=(self.frames, self.frequency))

    conv_1 = Conv1D(self.nb_filters_1, self.lenght_filters,
                    activation='relu', border_mode='same')(input_placeholder)
    pool_1 = MaxPooling1D(self.pool_size_1)(conv_1)


    conv_2 = Conv1D(self.nb_filters_1, self.lenght_filters,
                           border_mode='same', activation='relu')(pool_1)
    pool_2 = MaxPooling1D(self.pool_size_1)(conv_2)


    conv_3 = Conv1D(self.nb_filters_2, self.lenght_filters,
                    border_mode='same', activation='relu')(pool_2)
    pool_3 = MaxPooling1D(self.pool_size_2)(conv_3)

    global_mean = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(pool_3)
    global_max = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(pool_3)
    global_l2 = Lambda(l2_norm)(pool_3)

    concat = merge([global_mean, global_max, global_l2], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)

    hidden = Dense(self.dense_size, activation='relu')(concat)
    drop_1 = Dropout(self.dropout_prob_1)(hidden)
    hidden_2 = Dense(self.dense_size, activation='relu')(drop_1)
    drop_2 = Dropout(self.dropout_prob_1)(hidden_2)

    output = Dense(self.nb_classes, activation='softmax')(drop_2)

    model = Model(input=input_placeholder, output=output)

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    self.model = model
    return

def fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, validation_split):
    self.model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                   validation_split=validation_split)
    return
```

When I have this architecture the model does not learn past 25% accuracy but when on the `merge` layer I remove the L2 norm, i.e. `concat = merge([global_mean, global_max], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)` then it reaches around ~90% accuracy.

I changed nothing in the data or training procedure, **which leds to me to believe that there's something wrong with my custom function in the Lambda Layer**,but I can't figure out what?

Answer (score 0):

```
norm_layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(input layer)
```

You should specify across what axis you want to normalize your data. Usually, it is a one-dimensional vector, so the axis should be 1.